# Using javax @Transient annotation with a field of MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Javax's `@Transient` annotation when applied over an `@Entity` class' field will prevent the annotated field from being persisted into the database as a column. Is there a method to **selectively** achieve this behavior (of excluding the persistence of a certain column) for a field in a MappedSuperclass?
To clarify, I want some field `x` present in a MappedSuperclass to be persisted for some entity classes that extend the MappedSuperclass and excluded from persistence in some other extending entity classes.

I have tried shadowing the field `x` in the extending class and annotating it with `@Transient`, however, this doesn't seem to work. Is there any alternative approach that would enable this behavior?

Comment: you might put the annotation on the getter instead of the field and have the getter with the annotation on the actual class.

Comment: @juwil Tried using a getter with the annotation but that didn't work either

Comment: It should.. Do you have mixed placement of the anntoations? Maybe this could help: https://thorben-janssen.com/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/#Default_configuration_of_your_access_strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the children entity class that extends `@MappedSuperclass` , you can configure it to use the property access for this transient field .

So assuming a given `@MappedSuperclass` has a `@Transient` field :

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Parent {

    @Transient
    protected LocalDateTime createdTs;

}
```

For the children entity that want to include this transient field , you could do :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo extends Parent {

   @Id
   private Long id;


   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   @Column(name= "createTs")
   public LocalDateTime getCreatedTs() {
        return this.createdTs;
    }

}
```

And for the children entity that want to exclude this transient field , you could do :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo extends Parent {

   @Id
   private Long id;

}
```